# Suggestion to merge "knife" into "knives"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We use the plural form of nouns in tagging. Due to the non-standard pluralization, the system didn't prevent the creation of the [knife](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knife) tag but it should be merged into and a synonym of [knives](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knives), which has ten times the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, merged and [synonym created](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/knives/synonyms).